# How to update value in firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, updates

How to update the status as true:

[image: Firestore screenshot]

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); 
CollectionReference applicationsRef = rootRef.collection("Root"); 
DocumentReference applicationIdRef = applicationsRef.document("Registration"); 
applicationIdRef.update("Status",true).addOnCompleteListener(task -> { 

}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { 
  @Override public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { 
    Log.d("TAG", "onFailure: "+e); 
  } 
});
```

I was doing by this approach, but I was not getting how to go till status field .

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference applicationsRef = rootRef.collection("Root");
        DocumentReference applicationIdRef = applicationsRef.document("Registration");
        applicationIdRef.update("Status",true).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onFailure: "+e);
            }
        }); I was doing by this approach bu I was not getting how to go till status field

Comment: Please add the code to your question and not as a comment, so it can be formated. There is an edit button right under the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Map` field is (quite deeply) nested. To update nested fields, you use dot notation like this:

```
applicationIdRef.update("Map1.Map2.Map3.Status",true)
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [updating nested fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects)

But even then, since the value is in an array, there's no way update a single item in an array by its index. So `Map1.Map2.Map3.0.Status` won't work. You will need to:

1. Read the document from the database in your application code.
2. Update the item in the array in the nested field.
3. Write the entire array back to the database.

This [updating a single item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bandroid%5D+updating+a+single+item+in+an+array) has been covered extensively before, so I recommend checking out some of those answers too.